# can't add on to pointer pointing to first element in a file

Tags: c, pointers, file-io

text file only contain "hi".I expected it to point to the next charecter after c++ and print it but it's giving h↑ instead.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *ptr;
    char ch1;
    ptr = fopen("rough.txt", "r");
    ch1 = getc(ptr);
    char *c = &ch1;
    printf("%c", *c);
    c++;
    printf("%c", *c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you expect `c++` to read the next character from the file? That's not how it works. If you think of `c` as (originally) pointing to the first element of a one-element array, then `c++` will make it point to the second element of that one-element array. I.e. it will be pointing *out of bounds* and dereferencing it will lead to *undefined behavior*. If you want to read another character, you need to explicitly read it from the file, using e.g. `ch1 = getc(ptr)` *again*.

Comment: `ch1 = getc(ptr);` The type of `ch1` is not correct. It must be an `int` as `getc` returns an `int`.

Comment: If you really want to access the file as an array in memory, then *memory map* the file. But then the question is why would you want that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increment a pointer over the contents of the file, you should read more data.  A simple way to do that is to use `fread` to read a chunk of data rather than `getc`, which only reads one character.  For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *path = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "rough.txt";

    FILE *ifp = fopen(path, "r");
    if( ifp == NULL ){
        perror(path);
        return 1;
    }
    char buf[128];
    char *c = buf;
    size_t read_count = fread(buf, sizeof(char), sizeof buf, ifp);
    while( c < buf + read_count ){
        putchar(*c++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ch1 is a variable on the stack, and c was initailized with address of ch1.
using the post increment operator on it wont advance on the file but on the stack.

To read from the file you can create a buffer and use fread to fill it up then advance on it with the char * like you wanted to.

```c
int main()
{
    FILE *ptr = NULL;
    char buff[DESIRED_BUFF_SIZE] = {0};
    ptr = fopen("rough.txt", "r");
    fread(buff, <amount of chars to be read>, sizeof(char), ptr);
    /* print the chars from the buffer here*/

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getc` reads exactly *one* character from the file. Next time you call `getc` it will read the following character.

`c++;` will not read from the file. It will only increment the `c` pointer, after which `c` will point to an invalid memory location.

Don't make things more complicatd than they already are.

You want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE* inputfile;
  char ch;
  ptr = fopen("rough.txt", "r");
  
  if (ptr == NULL)  // you need to check if fopen succeeded
  {
    printf("File could not be opned\n");
    return 1;
  }

  ch = getc(inputfile);   // read first character
  printf("%c", ch);

  ch = getc(inputfile);   // read second character
  printf("%c", ch);

  fclose(inputfile);      // and don't forget to close
  return 0;
}
```

To read the whole file you need this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE* inputfile;
  int ch;                 // must be an int so that EOF works
  inputfile = fopen("rough.txt", "r");
  
  if (inputfile == NULL)  // you need to check if fopen succeeded
  {
    printf("File could not be opned\n");
    return 1;
  }

  while ((ch = getc(inputfile)) != EOF)
  {
    printf("%c", ch);
  }

  fclose(inputfile);
  return 0;
}
```

The details about `EOF` and why `ch` should be an `int` are explained in the chapter dealing with files in your C learning material.